# Error when adding columns and rows to datatbale in asp net vb:

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am having issues in creating my datatable in asp net (vb), table creates fine, but when I try and add columns or rows I get an error attempting it.  I have looked at all the samples and suggestion, compared to samples given but still no go.  Error is that Columns/rows is not a member of datatable, also when using intellisense, it does not give me value (Columns) or (Rows) as an option.  My code is pretty basic, newbie, very new and still learning.

Code is:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    Dim colid As New DataColumn("ID")

    Dim rw As DataRow = dt.NewRow()


    dt.Columns.Add(colid)

    rw(colid) = 1


    gridview1.DataSource = dt
    gridview1.DataBind()


End Sub
```

Very much TU

Comment: When you say "I have an error", make sure you say what the error is so you don't leave us guessing.